# can't get a titan graph instance from gremlin server

Tags: titan, gremlin

I started two gremlin server in two different machines ,for distribute computing.

Here is part of  **gremlin-server.yaml**

```
host: 192.168.200.115
port: 8182
threadPoolWorker: 3
gremlinPool: 6
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
serializedResponseTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {graph: conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties}
....
```

Here is part of **titan-cassandra-es.properties**

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
gremlin.graph=com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory
storage.hostname=192.168.200.115,192.168.200.116                                                                 
storage.cassandra.keyspace=titan                                                                         
storage.cassandra.replication-factor=3
....
```

It's all right when I started the gremlin server ,and connected to the gremlin server cluster:

> gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
>
> ==>Connected - dns121/192.168.200.116:8182, dns115/192.168.200.115:8182

But when I want to get the graph instance ,It's warning '**No such property: graph for class: groovysh_evaluate**'.

> gremlin> graph
>
> No such property: graph for class: groovysh_evaluate
>
> Display stack trace? [yN] n

But in [this page](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/server.html), it shows we can use graph directly after we connected to a gremlin server cluster.

So question is ,Which part I'm missing ?

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is bad. You are evaluating "graph" locally in the console and not on the server. You need to include `:submit` with your command or as shown in the documentation you referenced `:>` (the shortcut for `:sumbit`).

```
gremlin> :> graph
```

That should fix your problem. Note that in later versions of TinkerPop you can put the "remote" into console mode with:

```
gremlin> :remote console
```

which allows you to omit the `:>`. You can read more about that [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#console-remote-console). That feature is not available on Titan 1.0 but thought I would mention it.